# Silverlight 3 DataGrid (w/ PagedCollectionView) RowGroupHeaderStyles not reapplied on sort

Tags: sorting, silverlight-3.0, datagrid, grouping

I am trying to use a DataGrid with hidden group row headers (so that there is a sort boundary).  My style simply sets the visibility to collapsed (and I also am setting the SublevelIndent to 0 during the LoadingGroup event).   Initial display is exactly what I want, but the data grid is sorted the appearance is unstyled, and the default indent is apparent.  (When debugging the style is still present, and the sublevelindent still says 0).

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this in the past also.  I beleive you have to attach the `LoadingRowGroup` event and reset applicable properties on the `e.RowGroupHeader`.